# ASP.NET Core Web API controller action method argument is not correct

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a controller endpoint as shown here which accepts an `ExamCreateDTO` from the form.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IResponseData<uint>>> Create([FromForm] ExamCreateDTO examCreateDto)
```

These are the simplified `ExamCreateDTO` and `ReservationQuota` classes:

```
public class ExamCreateDTO : NamedObjectDTO
{
    public Scope Scope { get; set; }
    public Mode Mode { get; set; }
    public List<ReservationQuota> ReservationQuota { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IFormFile>? SampleFormFiles { get; set; }
}

public class ReservationQuota
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public short Reservation { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to send the request by filling the form in Swagger. I am getting all fields correctly including form files in `ExamCreateDTO`, except `ReservationQuota`.

`ReservationQuota` count is 0, even though I am sending data in Swagger.

When I inspect `HttpContext.Request.Form` keys and store data for `ReservationQuota` is proper like this:

```
{
  [ReservationQuota, { { "category": "General", "reservation": 50 } } ] 
}
```

Stuck with this for quite some time. Any help/hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok ... let´s try to trouble shoot this.  

Can you temporarily set ReservationQuota to a list containing a simpler type - for instance a string ?  

`
public List<string> ReservationQuota { get; set; }
` 

Then build a query from there and see what happens.

Comment: I had tried this and it works. If the list contains simple types like string, int it works. Problem comes when the list contains another class ie, in my case ReservationQuota class. Also I am getting the lits of IFormFiles correctly - public IEnumerable<IFormFile>? SampleFormFiles { get; set; }

Comment: I think that maybe this part is not correct:

{
  [ReservationQuota, { { "category": "General", "reservation": 50 } } ] 
}  
  
    Shouldn´t it be something like:  
    {
  "ReservationQuota":  [{ "category": "General", "reservation": 50 }, { "category": "General", "reservation": 25 } ] 
}

Comment: Swagger gives a form UI where i can add the ReservationQuota objects to a list. I have no control of how I add the objects in swagger. I tried sending the value you suggested [{ "category": "General", "reservation": 50 }, { "category": "Special", "reservation": 25 } ] for ReservationQuota in Postman and still the  ReservationQuota count is 0. The HttpContext.Request.Form keys and store data in this case is : {[ReservationQuota, {[{ "category": "General", "reservation": 50 }, { "category": "Special", "reservation": 25 } ]}]}

Comment: When I send the ReservationQuota as below in Postman UI as request body form data, it works.
ReservationQuota[0].Category General
ReservationQuota[0].Reservation 55
ReservationQuota[0].Category Special
ReservationQuota[0].Reservation 45

I will check the difference in the raw request formed in the working and non working case and update here shortly.

Comment: If in the request the ReservationQuota object is flattened as below, it works ReservationQuota[0].Category: "General"
ReservationQuota[0].Reservation: "50"
ReservationQuota[1].Category: "Special"
ReservationQuota[1].Reservation: "55"

But does not work in case the request has json object associated with ReservationQuota as below

ReservationQuota: "[{ "category": "General", "reservation": 50 }, { "category": "Special", "reservation": 25 } ]"

Comment: @BrianAndersen I have placed a simple project at git location:
https://github.com/manjunath-vadigeri/TestApp

There is an endpoint as below which accepts ExamCreateDto
public void Create([FromForm] ExamCreateDTO dto)

Comment: Thank you, manjuv. However .. it seems that you have forgotten to include your models and controllers ?  

Nevermind because I think the post that @brando-zhang has posted is more in the right direction than what we have been fiddling with.

Comment: All the models and controller in the file https://github.com/manjunath-vadigeri/TestApp/blob/master/TestApp/Controllers/WeatherForecastController.cs

@Brando Zhang's post talks more about sending the request from swagger, But I am not able to get the ReservationQuota object even when the request is sent through postman, as mentioned in the previous comments.

Comment: Ohh sorry .. I missed that in the WeatherForecastController. My bad.  I´ll look into it and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Following @Brandon Zhang s advice and using FromBody instead of FromForm I can get it to work.

Comment: By using [FromBody] , will we be able to send files also ? For my scenario I need to send both json data and few files.

Comment: Sorry .. I missed that, manjuv. I didn´t get uploading of files to work.

Comment: It seems that you are not the only one struggling with this, manjuv.  Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367602/upload-files-and-json-in-asp-net-core-web-api

Comment: @BrianAndersen Thanks for your support. I will try with the approach mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is known [issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1107) for the swagger UI and not resolved yet now.

The reason why the swagger send request doesn't match is it render the request as the json format but it should be multipart/form-data, since you set the fromform inside the controller method.

Like below:

[image]

So for this issue, we have two workaround now, one is creating a custom model binder to let the api to work with this specific request(please notice: after using this the right format for multiple form data will not work), another is using Frombody instead of fromform.

More details, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70587705/7609093).

Comment: I am facing problems sending the List via Postman as well. I tried sending the array [{ "category": "General", "reservation": 50 }, { "category": "Special", "reservation": 25 } ] for ReservationQuota in Postman and still the ReservationQuota count is 0. The HttpContext.Request.Form keys and store data in this case is : {[ReservationQuota, {[{ "category": "General", "reservation": 50 }, { "category": "Special", "reservation": 25 } ]}]}

Comment: If in the request the ReservationQuota object is flattened as below, it works ReservationQuota[0].Category: "General" ReservationQuota[0].Reservation: "50" ReservationQuota[1].Category: "Special" ReservationQuota[1].Reservation: "55" But does not work in case the request has json object associated with ReservationQuota as below ReservationQuota: "[{ "category": "General", "reservation": 50 }, { "category": "Special", "reservation": 25 } ]"