# Unable to read List<Object> when in controller we are reading the value as [FromForm]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, postman, swagger

Below is the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SurveyAnswers([FromForm] SaveSurveyAnswersModel model)
{
    return ( await _surveyQuestionsAnswersService.SurveyAnswers(model));
}
```

Below is the Payload Model:

```
public class SaveSurveyAnswersModel
    {
        public string? FeedbackMessage { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> answers { get; set; }
        public List<IFormFile> Image { get; set; }
 
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public string device_id { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class Answer
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string selectedOption { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

When i am passing the values in the payload, its unable to read the content in "answers". answers.Count always returns the value 0. I am not sure why.
Just the answers List is not being read
[image: SwaggerImage]

Comment: So what are you feeding it? You're not providing a sample input. I assume from your question that all other values are being read?

Comment: Yes all the other values are being read, its just the answers List that is not being read for some reason

Comment: My original question stands, what are you feeding it?

Comment: I am running it on swagger (multipart/form-data) , for Image i am getting an upload button, for answers i am getting an add object option where for each object the model is {id, selectedOption, type}. I am adding some random values and images in the payload for the rest

Comment: Please provide sample input. I am not sure how you expect anyone to help figure out why your input can't be parsed when you haven't shared what the input is.

Comment: not familiar with Swagger, but in your screenshot it looks like you are sending a JSON array for "answers".  FormData is key/value pairs with boundaries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger UI, array of objects in multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579248/swagger-ui-array-of-objects-in-multipart-form-data)